# Variables forwarding with SSH on Windows (without PuTTY)

Tags: windows, authentication, ssh

I have a *Vagrant/Puppet* VM that needs to execute SSH at a certain point and needs to **forward the GIT_* variables**, so that the server could Authenticate the automatic scripts without failing.

On Linux/Mac that's straightforward. But how to do it on Windows? (I have 8, but I guess is more or less the same for all >XP)

I searched over the net but all the solutions seem to rely on *PuTTY*, while I don't want to follow that approach (I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on *PuTTY* or *Cygwin*)

**How to forward environment variables through SSH over Windows?**

I cannot even find a way to set a custom *config* file where to put the directives.

Comment: In the third-last sentence I specified that I'd like to not rely nor on *Cygwin* or *PuTTY*.
I'm looking for a pure Windows+SSH solution that doesn't rely on having a *Linux-layer* installed.

Comment: If you aren't using PuTTY, what SSH client *are* you using?

Comment: *Sorry. My bad. Removing the comment.* Not sure how does the windows env. variables work. But you can have `ssh` client build under cygwin as standalone binary with no dependencies, which should give you all features you are looking for.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have the *ssh.exe* included with *Atlassian SourceTree*. I'm not sure if that is from OpenSSH or some other package. (EDIT: Yes, I just checked. That's OpenSSH)

Comment: @Jakuje env variables in Windows are key:value pairs as well, just stored differently; but I was wondering too how to give their coordinates to my SSH client. For what I can see *Cygwin* provides a closed environment with a Linux like filesystem-structure; if I can have a native EXE client I don't want to rely on additional layers (my VM is a project where I cannot add new required software as I want).

Comment: with openssh you can use `SendEnv` option on client and `AcceptEnv` on server, but I can't tell if it would work. There is nothing easier than to try. Running in `-vvv` debug mode should tell you what is send/accepted.

Comment: My problem is the SSH client is called from an automated script, and I cannot change the passed parameters (not atm at least). So I'm trying to understand how can I pass parameters via a configuration file, as it is easily possible on Linux/Mac with the *~/.ssh/config* or */etc/ssh/sshd_config* file. I cannot find something similar (and as simple) on Windows. I tried to add a *config* file into the *C:\Users\Kamafeather\.ssh\* but I have the impression it is not read.

Comment: There is probably a configuration file somewhere.  Check the OpenSSH documentation, or use Process Monitor to see what files the client tries to open when it starts up.